What makes people think Shakespeare's sonnets are autobiographical?
I often read that Shakespeare's sonnets are addressed to a Mr WH (although it was never Shakespeare, I believe, who addressed it but rather his publisher T.T., i.e. Thomas Thorpe) or to a dark lady but why is it never considered that they could just be a fictional depiction of love like Venus and Adonis?
So my question is, what makes people think that sonnets are to be based on realistic love interest of Shakespeare himself and not purely fictional?

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. If you think that it "is never considered that they could just be a fictional depiction of love", you are quite mistaken. Just because the sonnets are dedicated (not "addressed" as you write), that does not mean he is the addressee of the sonnets.

@GarethRees Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited accordingly

@Tsundoku I have just never read any article which talks about such and wanted communities answers as to if there have been any such considerations and why are such considerations not main stream?

[are based, not are to be based]

We simply don’t know enough about Shakespeare’s personal life to be able to match characters and incidents from the sonnets to his biography. So the only evidence for the sonnets being autobiographical is “internal”, meaning that it comes from the text of the sonnets themselves. Here’s a short summary of this evidence by James Schiffer:

Those who believe the Sonnets are autobiographical base their view on the assumption that these are the only poems Shakespeare wrote in first person, as well as on the fact that the poet-speaker says his name is “Will”,† puns many times upon that name,‡ and perhaps alludes to Shakespeare’s profession as an actor-dramatist in sonnets 110 and 111.§ Furthermore, under the influence of the Romantic aesthetic that for a poem to be good it must also be sincere, many readers have concluded that only genuine feeling based in actual life experiences could produce such powerful rhymes. Finally, proponents of the so-called “personal theory” (i.e., the Sonnets as autobiography) maintain that if Shakespeare had wanted to invent a story, he would have done a much better job of telling it. The allusions to events so inadequately rendered in the sequence suggest to these readers an origin in real-life experience; Shakespeare, they argue, must have been writing to people who participated in or at least knew about such events and who therefore did not need them to be explained.
James Schiffer (1999). ‘Reading New Life into Shakespeare’s Sonnets: A Survey of Criticism’. In James Schiffer, editor (1999). Shakespeare’s Sonnets: Critical Essays, page 14. New York: Routledge.
† Sonnet 136: “And then thou lov’st me for my name is Will.” ‡ For example, sonnet 135: “thou hast thy will, and Will to boot”. § For example, sonnet 110: “made my self a motley to the view”. 

In support of his last point (that is, considered as a fictional narrative, the sonnets seem very hard to interpret), Schiffer quotes A. C. Bradley:

No capable poet, much less a Shakespeare, intending to produce a merely ‘dramatic’ series of poems, would dream of inventing a story like that of these sonnets, or, even if he did, of treating it as they treat it. The story is very odd and unattractive. Such capacities as it has
are but slightly developed. It is left obscure, and some of the poems are unintelligible to us because they contain allusions of which we can make nothing. Now all this is perfectly natural if the story is substantially a real story of Shakespeare himself and of certain other persons; if the sonnets were written from time to time as the relations of the persons changed, and sometimes in reference to particular incidents; and if they were written for one or more of these persons (far the greater number for only one), and perhaps in a few cases for other friends,—written, that is to say, for people who knew the details and incidents of which we are ignorant. But it is all unnatural, well-nigh incredibly unnatural, if, with the most sceptical critics, we regard the sonnets as a free product of mere imagination.
A. C. Bradley (1909). ‘Shakespeare the Man’. In Oxford Lectures on Poetry, page 331. London: Macmillan.

In the 1780 edition of the sonnets, the first to be published with extensive critical notes, the editor Thomas Malone simply assumes that the poems are autobiographical. In his introduction he jumps straight into the problem of identifying “Mr W. H.”, whom he assumes, without argument, to be the same as the addressee of the “fair youth” sonnets:

Dr. Farmer supposes that many of these Sonnets are addressed to our author’s nephew Mr. William Harte. But this, I think, may be doubted. Shakspeare’s sister, Joan Harte, was born in April, 1569. Supposing her to have married at so early an age as sixteen, her eldest son William could not have been more than twelve years old in 1598, at which time these Sonnets were composed, though not published for several years afterwards. Many of them are written to show the propriety of marriage; ard therefore cannot well be supposed to be addressed to a school-boy. […] To this person, whoever he was, one hundred and twenty of the following poems are addressed; the remaining twenty-eight are addressed to a lady.
Thomas Malone (1780). Supplement to the Edition of Shakespeare’s Plays, volume 1, page 579. London: C. Bathurst, etc.

Malone’s confidence in the biographical interpretation must have influenced later responses to the poems from readers of his edition.

The poem "House" by Robert Browning puts the anti-autobiographical case into verse: "Shakespeare unlocked his heart … Did Shakespeare? If so, the less Shakespeare he!"
